# translation into es6 import

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, import

How to translate to es6 import?

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('body-parser-xml')(bodyParser);
```

I know only 50%

```
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
```

But how to add the last 50%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second part imports and calls a function, passing `bodyParser`. Try

```
import * as bodyParserXml from 'body-parser-xml';

bodyParserXml(bodyParser);
```

Comment: Thx! 
Now I have the next problem:
TS2339: Property 'xml' does not exist
on type 'typeof bodyParser'.
I know, that's related to TypeScript, but @types/body-parser-xml didn't fix it.

I tried to use it as middleware:
app.use(bodyParser.xml());

I find some kind of workaround.

import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import bodyParserXml from 'body-parser-xml';

bodyParserXml(bodyParser);
const bodyParserPlusXMLParser: any = bodyParser;

app.use(bodyParserPlusXMLParser.xml());

Comment: bodyParserXml is not a function , why I got this error ?