# How to transform the require to import mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, es6-modules

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

require('body-parser-xml')(bodyParser);
```

My code is ES6 module(import) , I don't know how to transform the above code to ES6 code .

```
import express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as bodyParserXml from 'body-parser-xml';

bodyParserXml(bodyParser);

app.use(bodyParserXml());
```

the errors like these as following ,
Apr 18 09:12:55 PM  file:///opt/render/project/src/app.js:8
Apr 18 09:12:55 PM  bodyParserXml(bodyParser);
Apr 18 09:12:55 PM  TypeError: bodyParserXml is not a function

the solution according this article .
[translation into es6 import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62303949/translation-into-es6-import)

Comment: You first add to `package.json` following: `"type": "module",`, and then you can use imports `import express from "express"`

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is the issue?

Comment: "yeh, Is that right ?" — Do you have some reason to think it isn't?

Comment: oK ,let me take the double check

Comment: TypeError: bodyParserXml is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the library creator](https://github.com/fiznool/body-parser-xml/issues/19) you shoud try this:

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import bodyParserXml from 'body-parser-xml';

bodyParserXml(bodyParser);
app.use(bodyParser.xml());
```

Comment: Yes , it works ,  need this code as  app.use(bodyParser.xml());  Thx !